# Can't read offline XML in Windows Phone

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, deserialization

i have this xml saved in my projecy (folder/xml.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <myxml>
    <table name="dati">
      <column name="Ordine">1</column>
      <column name="Data">07/11/2011</column>
      <column name="Nome_Comico">Massimo</column>
      <column name="Frase">ciao ciao</column>
      <column name="Descrizione">ola ola</column>
      <column name="URL_img">foto.png</column>
    </table>
    <table name="dati">
      <column name="Ordine">1</column>
      <column name="Data">07/11/2011</column>
      <column name="Nome_Comico">Massimo</column>
      <column name="Frase">ciao ciao</column>
      <column name="Descrizione">ola ola</column>
      <column name="URL_img">foto.png</column>
    </table>
  </myxml>
```

my code for now is:

```
    public ComiciPage()
    {
        if (InternetIsAvailable())
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var xdoc = XDocument.Load("folder/xml.xml");
            var result = from o in xdoc.Document.Descendants("table")
            select new myObject(o.Element("Nome_Comico").Value,o.Element("Nata").Value,o.Element("Ordine").Value);
            Debug.WriteLine(result.ToList<myObject>());
        }
        else
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MyApp;component/App.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
    public class myObject
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
        public string Property3 { get; set; }
        public myObject(string _property1, string _property2, string _property3)
        {
            this.Property1 = _property1;
            this.Property1 = _property1;
            this.Property1 = _property1;
        }
    }
```

the problem is that i can't read it. i've learned how to parse an online xml, but an easy one, and some offline tutorial... but i can't read it because i have that strange node...
someone can help me?
for now, i must only take the values and put it in the debug, just for see that is working, after i will use it.

thanks everyone

Comment: in doucment you have `Nome_Comico` but in read code it's `nome`

Comment: edited. but it's not this the problem.
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is wrong relative path. You can try to open the file stored in isolated storage as stream, if you don't forget to set property "Content" for it in project. Then, you should use method which requires stream object as parameter instead of file path:

```
 
using (var appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
using (var file = appStorage.OpenFile("folder/xml.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    XElement.Load(file);
 }
```

Comment: but after that, i find this error:
var result = from o in xdoc.Document.Descendants("table")
on xdoc